# Rails - use code(css, js, html) from server on client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I had a  application rails built with bootstrap and simple form.
Here I have to show the UI patterns how they actually look like. That means I have to show the 
patterns like menu bar, accordian patterns examples in my application. For that I am storing the pattern code html,css,js in database.

Here my requirement is I have to show the actual code pattern view from the  stored record(css,js,html) without any css/js conflicts.

How can  eneter the html,css,js code dynamically in a partial or page to show that 
in a fancybox in rails.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `html_safe` or `raw` to render your content as a normal string on views. For instance:

in your controller:

```
@x = YOUR_CODE_FROM_DB
```

in your view:

```
<%= @x.html_safe %>
# <%= raw @x %> is also ok in this case
```

NOTICE: you can use `html_safe` on models, but `raw` is declared on a helper, so you can just use it on controllers and views.

-- edit --

more example:

on controller:

```
@hello = 'alert("hi");'
@body = 'body{ background: red; }'
```

on view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  <%= raw @hello %>
</script>

<style type="text/css" media="all">
  <%= @body.html_safe %>
</style>
```

Comment: But it is in the case of html tags. I am unable to include the Js code from the database into a view

Comment: And I cannot add in partial view like this <script>

   <%= @pattern.pat_js %>

</script>                Here pat_js is data that contains js content from the pattern tabl

Comment: And I waS UNABLE TO ADD css too <style>
<%= raw @pattern.pat_css %>

</style>

Comment: can you get it in the console?

Comment: on your app directory, enter `rails console`, get @pattern, which you are using, and see whether you can get the data properly. otherwise,  you can just print it on server console. anyways, you need to check there is correct data in `@pattern`.

Comment: Yes I am getting the data fine. Do u have any idea to include css only for the particular partial dynamically from the database record?

Comment: hi RANZIT, I have edited the post and added a new example that worked on my machine. i am super sure the example works, if you have something similar to it, but you still can't get your code work, maybe you have done something else wrong. if so, you need to provide more information.

Comment: if you are very sure there is no bug in the code you get from db, I am guessing that you have something else wrong, which makes your code don't work. for instance, maybe you have another js that has bugs and makes your code even have not been executed. please use your browser( Chrome is recommended ) to debug.

Comment: Great!!!! ... Thanks Brian that was worked like a charm for me. And that was the apt title for my thread to get problem solved.